# How can I import multiple csv files from a folder into sql, into their own separate table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, csv, ssis

I would like some advice on the best way to go about doing this. I have multiple files all with different layouts and I would like to create a procedure to import them into new tables in sql.

I have written a procedure which uses xp_cmdshell to get the list of file names in a folder and the use a cursor to loop through those file names and use a bulk insert to get them into sql but I dont know the best way to create a new table with a new layout each time.

I thought if I could import just the column row into a temp table then I could use that to create a new table to do my bulk insert into. but I couldn't get that to work.

So whats the best way to do this using SQL? I am not that familiar with .net either. I have thought about doing this in SSIS, I know its easy enough to load multiple files which have the same layout in SSIS but can it be doe with variable layouts?

thanks

Comment: I am pretty sure there is no easy way to do this, you would not only need the column names, column count, but you would need to know the datatype for each column, which does not exist in the bcp file.  if you have a format file for each bcp file, then you could potentially parse the format file, but that would be a huge effort.  i'd be more curious why you need to do this though.

Comment: Have looked at [SQL Server Management Objects (SMO)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162169.aspx)? As @Greg points out, you need to suss out the column names, counts, and data types. If that can be done, then SMO will let you create tables in .Net code. As a side note, there is a extended store procedure (xp_dirtree), that will list files. DBAs, with good reason, are reluctant to enable xp_cmdshell.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [BimlScript](http://bimlscript.com/GetStarted/AboutBimlScript) to make the whole process automated where you just point it at the path of interest and it writes all the SSIS and T-SQL DDL for you, but for the effort involved in writing the C# you'd need, you may as well just put the data dump into SQL Server in the C#, too.

You can use SSIS to solve this issue, though, and there are a few levels of effort to pick from.

The easiest is to use the [SQL Server Import and Export Wizard](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141209.aspx) to create SSIS packages from your Excel spreadsheets that will dump the sheet into its own table. You'd have to run this wizard every time you had a new spreadsheet you wanted to import, but you could save the package(s) so that you could re-import that spreadsheet again.

The next level would be to edit a saved SSIS package (or write one from scratch) to parameterize the file path and the destination table names, and you could then re-use that package for any spreadsheets that followed the same format.

Further along would be to write a package that determined with of the packages from the previouw level to call. If you can query the header rows effectively, you could probably write an SSIS package that accepted a path as an input parameter, found all the Excel sheets in that path, queried the header rows to determine the spreadsheet format, and then pass that information to the parameterized package for that format type.

SSIS development is, of course, its own topic - [Integration Services Features and Tasks on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522537.aspx) is a good place to start. SSIS has its quirks, and I highly recommend learning BimlScript if you want to do a lot of SSIS development. If you'd like to talk over what the ideas above would require in more detail, please feel free to message me.